# Path errors when using GNU Stow

Tags: stow

I am trying to get started with GNU Stow. I have defined `STOW_DIR` to point to a personal path:

```
STOW_DIR=/some/path
```

I then build a package of my choice from the tarball and install it under `STOW_DIR`. In this case, I am building `stow` itself (i.e. I am [bootstrapping](http://www.inductiveload.com/posts/basic-use-of-gnu-stowxstow/) stow itself into Stow):

```
./configure --prefix=$STOW_DIR/stow
make
make install prefix=$STOW_DIR/stow
```

And then I build the symlinks:

```
cd $STOW_DIR
./stow/bin/stow stow
```

but at this point I get the following error:

> `stow: ERROR: The stow directory ../../../../some/path does not contain package stow (No such file or directory)`

why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks remarkably similar to a bug [discussed in the `help-stow` mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.stow.bugs/8820), which coincidentally surfaced within the last 48 hours.

This is probably a bug, which was fixed [in this commit](https://github.com/aspiers/stow/commit/c500216f20b081fae0799253d1d86536d48ff6ba). You may try cloning [that branch](https://github.com/aspiers/stow/tree/canonical-paths) and see if it fixes the issue for you.

Comment: I think this is not really an answer. In my opinion, you can either put the link as a comment, or improve your post by explaining the main message from the linked web-page. (and obviously clearly state the source)

Comment: Thanks @Adam Spiers, which git repository are you referring to? Looking at the log, the last commit at: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/stow.git/log/ seems to have been on 2012-07-09. Is Stow still hosted at savannah?

Comment: @user815423426 Please re-read [my post on the mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.stow.bugs/8821) which explicitly states the location of the git repository.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpiers. When building from the git repository, what else should I do before running `./configure` ? (there is no `./configure` file)

Comment: Run `aclocal`, `autoconf`, and `automake`.